# How to stream a video from an https url in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, screensaver

I'm trying to make a screensaver for Mac, that streams a simple mp4 video from a backend server. I'm not used to coding for Mac or in Objective-c, so I'm pretty lost. Until now I've figured out how to load a video locally, but when I try to switch out the file URL to an HTTPS URL it doesn't seem to work. This is how I'm loading the local mp4 file right now:

```objectivec
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:MainScript.class] URLForResource: @"video" withExtension: @"mp4"];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL: url];
NSArray *assetKeys = @[@"playable", @"hasProtectedContent"];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:assetKeys];
NSKeyValueObservingOptions options = NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew;
VideoPlayer *player = [VideoPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: playerItem];
[playerItem addObserver: player forKeyPath: @"status" options: options context: PlayerItemContext];
player.volume = 0;
```

As I said before, I'm not used to code in Objective-c, so I'm not 100 percent certain that this is the code that creates the local video stream, but I'm pretty sure it is.

What I want to do from here, is to replace the file URL: `@"video"` with an HTTPS URL like this: `@"https://example.com/video"`. Everything is working on the backend server, so my problem is only how to load the video on a Mac screensaver.

As I understand it, I'm using `AVPlayerItem` to load the video right now. I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but if there is, please tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using VLCKit, I'm pretty sure that can do HTTPS out of the box.

Comment: I've tried to implement VLCKit into the screensaver, but I can't get it to work at all. Can you maybe guide me? or do you maybe know how to do it with the example in my question (with AVPlayer), which I already got working, but only with local videos?